# Como utilizar o using "Renci.SshNet" no VSCode em ambiente MacOS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, ssh, osx

```
using System;
using Renci.SshNet;


namespace SSHTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SshClient cSSH = new SshClient(args[1], 22, args[2], args[3]);
            cSSH.Connect();
            SshCommand c = cSSH.RunCommand(args[1]);
            cSSH.Disconnect();
            cSSH.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

O código compilou sem erro com o seguinte comando: "csc Program.cs ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Renci.SshNet.dll"

E quando tentado executar, utilizando o comando: "mono Program.exe" foi retornado a seguinte resposta:
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Renci.SshNet, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Renci.SshNet, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Alguém consegue me ajudar em como utilizar esta Library, Renci.SshNet, na IDE VSCode no ambiente MacOS ?